# Issues connecting Google Cloud SQL from Google Cloud Instance

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a site hosted on google compute engine with phpMyAdmin and MySQL working fine. I recently created a Cloud SQL instance but I'm having issues defining its config settings in my database file

Current config file has the following

```
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "my_password";
$db['default']['database'] = "my_database";
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
```

after uploading the SQL to Google Cloud SQL I changed the config to below but it isn't working

```
$db['default']['username'] = "new_user";
$db['default']['password'] = "my_password";
$db['default']['database'] = "my_database";
$db['default']['hostname'] = "google_cloud_sql_server_ip";
```